# Where does Fluent-Bit S3 Output timestamp come from and how can I change it?

Tags: fluent-bit

I set my S3 output as below:

[OUTPUT]
Name s3
Match 3-year*
bucket my-bucket-name
region ap-northeast-1
upload_timeout 60m
compression gzip
store_dir /app/opt/fluentbit/buffer
s3_key_format /$TAG[1]/$TAG[2]/%Y/%m/%d/$TAG[3]-$UUID.gz
s3_key_format_tag_delimiters :

in S3, I finde the logs are not output as expected. for example, the logs from 0:00 to 9:00 of local time(JST) are stored in the previous day's folder.
/2024/03/09 has logs of 2024/03/09 from 0:00 to 9:00 in local time.
it seems S3 is using the UTC standard time to decide which folder to put the created log.

how can I put logs of 2024/03/09 from 0:00 to 9:00 in local time into /2024/03/09 folder?
I tried the filter below but not work
[FILTER]
Name Lua
Match *
call append_tag
code function append_tag(tag, timestamp, record) local_time = os.time() new_time = local_time + 9*60*60 new_timestamp = os.date("!%Y-%m-%d-%TZ", new_time) new_record = record new_record["date"] = new_timestamp return 1, new_timestamp, new_record end